# How to ensure ScheduledService stops when last window closes in JavaFX

Tags: concurrency, javafx-8

I am using a ScheduledService to ensure that the server connection is kept alive while the application is open, and the user is not actively interacting with the application.

There are times when the application thread doesn't end when the application is closed, and I am assuming that it is likely the ScheduledService which is causing my issues.

Since my application will consist of many stages open at one point, I can't put a kill in the close of the window to stop the service.  Is there any other way to see if a stage is currently open during the execution of the thread, and if not to cancel the service?

```
//Service set up
service = new KeepSessionAliveService() ;
service.setPeriod(Duration.minutes(REPEAT_PERIOD));
service.setDelay(Duration.minutes(INITIAL_DELAY));
service.start();

private class KeepSessionAliveService extends ScheduledService<Void> {
    @Override
    protected Task<Void> createTask() {
        return new Task<Void>() {
            @Override
            protected Void call() throws ClientProtocolException, IOException {
                pingServerToKeepAlive();
                return null;
            }
        };
    }
}
```

If this isn't the best way to handle I am open to suggestions.

Thanks.

EDIT:
I am attempting to provide a default implementation of server access where the developer simply calls a wrapper method providing the needed expected class definition.  When the call is invoked, it will provide the progress alert while the process is running, and then close it when it's done.  Initially I tried with a service, but couldn't seem to get it to work so it was suggested to be to try the following:

```
public <T> void executeServerCall(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String message, Stage stage, Class<T> valueType, Consumer<T> success, Consumer<Exception> failure) {
    Alert progressAlert = displayProgressDialog(message, stage);
    Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {
           try {
               T result = executeServerCall(serviceRequest, valueType);
               Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    forcefullyHideDialog(progressAlert);
                    success.accept(result);
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    forcefullyHideDialog(progressAlert);
                    failure.accept(e);
                });
            }

    });
}
```

Based on your response I did prove out that it was this code that is holding the application thread running, rather than the service.  If I can accomplish what I need with a service at this point, I would be more than happy to change it.  However I couldn't find a way to do the following:

```
public <T> void executeServerCall(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String message, Stage stage, Class<T> valueType, Consumer<T> success, Consumer<Exception> failure) {

    Service<valueType> service = ....
```

Comment: By default, a `ScheduledService` (and a `Service`) will create a daemon thread on which to execute the tasks created. (See [Javadocs for `Service`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/javafx/api/javafx/concurrent/Service.html)). So unless you are specifying an executor for the service (in which case show that code), the service should not be the culprit here.

Comment: That is what I assumed.  However when I run from Eclipse this services stops when the windows close, however on the EXE the FX thread continues to run.  I am not specifying an executor on this thread, but it's the only thing I have scheduled.  I also use the following: Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor().execute(() -> {}); to interact with my server.  However this thread has long stopped before I close the application, so I don't think it could be that one?  I can't see why the application thread will not stop.

Comment: `Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor()` creates an executor which uses a single thread to execute any `Runnable` you pass it, but the thread will persist after (each) `Runnable` completes unless the `Runnable` fails due to an exception. (See [docs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executors.html#newSingleThreadExecutor--).) From your code snippet it looks like you are creating many of these executors, which is a very bad idea as eventually your app will hit thread starvation. Edit the details of what you are doing there into your question, or create a [MCVE].

Answer (score 1):

You are creating many single threaded executors on which you are performing each individual call to your server. Each of those executors creates it own non-daemon thread, which then sits waiting for the next runnable to execute.

If all these calls to the server are supposed to happen on a single thread, you should create a single executor to do this. (Indeed, if you want them to happen on multiple threads, you should still create a single executor, just one that uses multiple threads, instead of a single thread.)

So:

```
private final ExcecutorService serverCallExec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor();

// ...

public <T> void executeServerCall(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String message, Stage stage, Class<T> valueType, Consumer<T> success, Consumer<Exception> failure) {
    Alert progressAlert = displayProgressDialog(message, stage);
    serverCallExec.execute(() -> {
           try {
               T result = executeServerCall(serviceRequest, valueType);
               Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    forcefullyHideDialog(progressAlert);
                    success.accept(result);
                });
            } catch (Exception e) {
                Platform.runLater(() ->
                {
                    forcefullyHideDialog(progressAlert);
                    failure.accept(e);
                });
            }

    });
}
```

To get the executor to terminate its thread when the application closes, either arrange to call `serverCallExec.shutdown();` from your `Application.stop()` method, or make the thread used by the executor a daemon thread by specifying a thread factory:

```
private final ExecutorService serverCallExec = Executors.newSingleThreadedExecutor((Runnable r) -> {
    Thread t = new Thread(r);
    t.setDaemon(true);
    return t ;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for the suggestion.
While we were going back and forth, I attempted this.

```
public <T> void executeServerCall(ServiceRequest serviceRequest, String message, Stage stage, Class<T> valueType, Consumer<T> success, Consumer<Throwable> failure) {
    Service<T> service = new Service<T>(){
        @Override
        protected Task<T> createTask() {
            return new Task<T>() {
                @Override
                protected T call() throws Exception {
                    return executeServerCall(serviceRequest, valueType);
                }
            };
        }
    };
    service.setOnSucceeded(event -> success.accept(service.getValue()));
    service.setOnFailed(event -> failure.accept(service.getException()));

    ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(service);
    pd.setContentText(message);
    pd.initModality(Modality.WINDOW_MODAL);
    pd.initOwner(stage);

    service.start();
}
```

This solves my issue and uses the concurrency service to handle my issues.  I am not sure why this wouldn't work before (I likely had some weird setup around the creation of the service).

Is this a better solution that the one you posted above for my needs?  I just wanted to abstract away the plumbing of the call.  This seems to do it.

Comment: In fact there is no hesitation now when the last window on the exe closes, the thread goes away.  Thank you so much for explaining what I was doing incorrectly!!

Comment: That's definitely cleaner if it works for your requirements. It will terminate gracefully, because by default the thread(s) created for a `ScheduledService` are daemon threads.

Comment: It works like a charm.  Thanks again, really appreciate your help and insight on these forums.  It's how I originally attempted to do it, and I think it was that I was attempted to do: Service<valueType> since it was passed in rather than Service<T>.  Just dumb mistake.  I was provided the Executor solution, and didn't think twice since it worked.  But this is cleaner, and how I wanted to do it in the first place.